# pd.merge не работает

Tags: python, pandas

Есть простенький код

```
import pandas as pd

relig = pd.read_excel('Religion in the United States by State and the District of Columbia (2014).xlsx')
birth = pd.read_excel('List of U.S. states and territories by birth and death rates in 2017.xlsx')

birth = birth.rename(columns={"state": "Region"})
relig = relig.replace(['<1.0', '<1,0'], 0)

pd.merge(relig, birth, how='outer')
```

И не смотря на одинаковость значений столбцов *Region* этих фреймов, получается такой результат

[image: Вырезка из объединенного фрейма]

То есть он не видит общих значений между фреймами, а они есть.

Собственно сами файлы .xlsx: https://yadi.sk/d/iX5-RapA3zWQgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что в таблице 'List of U.S. states and territories by birth and death rates in 2017.xlsx' названия штатов начинаются с пробелов. Для программы строки 'Arizona' и ' Arizona' не равны. Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
relig = pd.read_excel('Religion in the United States by State and the District of Columbia (2014).xlsx')
birth = pd.read_excel('List of U.S. states and territories by birth and death rates in 2017.xlsx')
birth = birth.rename(columns={"state": "Region"})
relig = relig.replace(['<1.0', '<1,0'], 0)
# Удаляем пробелы из строк с названием регионов в датафрейме birth
birth['Region'] = birth['Region'].map(lambda x: x[1:len(x)])
res = pd.merge(relig, birth, on='Region', how='outer')
```

Comment: birth["Region"].str.strip() может?